# how to always have same number of fixed width <li> per row in a single fluid <ul>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Lets say I have 10 `<li>` in a single fluid `<ul>`. If I resize the browser the `<li>` will go next row. Lets also say we want the `<ul>` centered on the page:

Html:

```
<ul>
   <li>Lorem</li>
   <li>Lorem</li>
   <li>Lorem</li>
   <li>Lorem</li>
   <li>Lorem</li>
   <li>Lorem</li>
   <li>Lorem</li>
   <li>Lorem</li>
   <li>Lorem</li>
   <li>Lorem</li>
</ul>
```

Css:

```
ul {
   text-align: center;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

That will center our `<ul>` but obviously if we have 10 `<li>` and the page/screen size only manages to have 4 `<li>` per row, then we will have 2 `<li>` centered in the last row and not aligned to the first `<li>` of the previous rows.

I am not sure if what I am trying to achive can be done only using css ( I presume if each rows was a different `<ul>` then it'd be ok, but I only want 1 `<ul>`.

So I wonder if the trick can and/or should be done using jquery?

Comment: give your ul a fixed width

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated this is a fluid layout. Updated the question

Comment: yes but I did say 10 ;) - Anyway even if we'd have 11, we'll still have the same issue. 5 <li> per row, and the last <li> would be centered and not aligned left.

Comment: The problem is that you are center aligning them, if you are wanting the rows to line up down the left you are going to need to align them left rather than center, the way you are doing it none of your lis will be left aligned unless all your rows are the same length (as they are when they are all lorem)

Comment: yes preceisly, but then I am not sure how I would have the <ul> centered on the page. It's tricky.

Comment: why don't you try with `min-width & min-height`

Comment: ok, I'll give it another try with margin: 0 auto on the ul and keep the float left on the <li>. I did try it tho.

Comment: hi that won't work, I have come up with a solution - see answer below

Comment: @rob.m If it weren't for the fact that you need to center your items, CSS Columns would be perfect:  http://jsfiddle.net/x5vwf/

Comment: yea they're nice, just wanted to do a center layout here, but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your ul in containing div and align that center and then align your ul left and make it inline-block:

http://jsfiddle.net/pdfbG/

**html**

```
<div>
    <ul>
       <li>Test</li>
       <li>Lorem</li>
       <li>Another one</li>
       <li>Lorem</li>
       <li>Lorem</li>
       <li>Lorem</li>
       <li>Lorem</li>
       <li>Lorem</li>
       <li>Lorem</li>
       <li>Lorem</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**css**

```
div {text-align:center;}
ul {
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:left;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Bingo! That's perfect :) Thanks a lot

Comment: Doesn't IE hate inline-block?

Comment: ie6 does but I hate ie6 users so I don't care

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {
 text-align: center;
 display:table;
 width: 400px; //example
}
```

li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    }

Comment: yes but this is with a fixed ul width. What about a fluid one?

Comment: then you can use ul width as percentage.

Comment: pete's answer is what I was looking for, check it and thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

use calc function in width

```
width:calc(100%-your margins in px or %);
```

this works i hope

Comment: is this html 5 only? Never heard of calc

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-calc-function/ tutorial 

and check compatibility here http://caniuse.com/calc

Answer (score 0):

You need to make 10% width of your `li` elements to make them fluid:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px #AAA solid;
    width: 10%;
    font-size: 14px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CdWaY/

Comment: hey yes, thanks for the effort. But not really what I was asking :)

Comment: Hm, you want to have fixed number of `li` in the row.

Comment: yes but <li> in % wasn't specified as a requirement :) I will updated my question as you are correct, it has to be specified or it get confusing. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Simply make the width 10% and they will resize on their own

```
width: 10%;
```